# Broadcast Joins in Spark SQL

Tags: apache-spark-sql

I am new to Spark SQL. My role involves writing Spark sql queries for data transformation. Recently I got  introduced to `Broadcast Hash Join` (`BHJ`) in Spark SQL. I understand that a `BHJ` performs very well when the broadcasted table is very small and can be induced by using query hints.
For e.g.

```
select /*+ BROADCAST(B) */
*
from A
Left Join B
on A.id = B.id;
```

I have also read that there are 2 types of Broadcast Joins - `Driver BHJ` & `Executor BHJ` (the latter yields better performance).

Hence, when I use a Broadcast hint in my query, does Spark use a `Driver BHJ` or an `Executor BHJ` ?

How can I command Spark (via hints etc) to induce an `Executor BHJ` instead of a `Driver BHJ` ?

*I use Spark SQL 2.4.*

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

For spark 2.4 you don’t t have to mention any hints.

You can set below spark config to set the limit of small data set which can be broadcasted, by default it is 10 Mb.

```
spark.conf.set("spark.sql.autoBroadcastJoinThreshold" "<value in kb>")
```